# Zooming to selection in arcpy.mapping and only seeing selected features?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, zoom

I selected data by using select layer by attribute, then I need to only select these selection and zoom in to the selection. 
my code is this, it can zoom in base on the scale I set, but I see other adjacent polygon that has other Code_No, why?

```
Layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "lyr", df)       
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", "Code_NO = '%s'"%mycodeNo)           
df.extent = lyrLayer1.getSelectedExtent()
df.scale *= 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If your layer is called "lyr" and you have already created your map document (mxd) and data frame (df) objects, then the following should have a better chance of working.  I am not sure about your SQL expression so have hardcoded a value. For your initial testing use something you know exists and then work on the SQL expression after that.

```
lyrLayer1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "lyr", df)[0]     
lyrLayer1.definitionQuery = ''' "Code_NO" = 'TEST_VALUE' '''
df.extent = lyrLayer1.getSelectedExtent()
```