# Definition Query then Zoom to Layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, zoom, definition-query

I'm trying to create something in here. I want to have an automated process of doing a DEFINITION QUERY then ZOOM TO LAYER with one step.

the concept is like that, a dialog comes up with one form that asks me to put a unique id for the specific parcel that I'm trying to look up, then I type the parcel numder then hit OK then it brings me to that specific parcel directly.

1. Dialog pop-up
2. Empty form to be filled
3. Hit ok
4. It zooms directly to that parcel

How can I do this using ArcPy?

An automated way to do the definition query then zoom to layer.

Comment: Have you got the dialog working? I am not sure if you can get to the layers' definition query via python but you can make a layer with a where clause, this should reduce the apparent extent and then zoom to layer.

Comment: The problem here is that I'm new to both python and modelbuilder. I'm just thinking of a way to do a definition query on a specific attribute then after finding it it will zoom to layer. Simple yet complicated! But if I get a solution to this one I'm surely will have the experience to do the upcoming tasks.

Comment: There is code provided in an answer to possible duplicate of [How to zoom to selection in arcpy.mapping and only see selected features?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85231/how-to-zoom-to-selection-in-arcpy-mapping-and-only-see-selected-features)

Comment: Your biggest problem is the dialog box. How do you feel about C# or VB.net instead of python? Much more control but less portability.

Comment: That would be perfect if you could show me the way to do it, can't wait to be at ESRIUC! Many ideas but less means! I would be thankful, Sir.

Comment: Let's say that I have an attribute called parcels and there are 100 parcels, I want a script or model that would do the Definition Query or SelectByAttribute automatically so that I only put the parcel number then it zooms to that parcel.

Comment: You would need to download Visual Studio Express **2012** and install the SDK. There are references to get started on the Esri help. ArcObjects (the C# or VB.net SDK for ArcMap) is more complicated than python but is based on forms. If you are not so keen on that you will need a python forms install like pyWin (I don't endorse this product, I just like their editor) there are other forms for python to investigate.

Answer (score 4):

The definition query of the layer and zooming to is the easy part:

```
import arcpy

# Assuming that Value is set by the form, there is only one data frame
# and the layer name is LayerName

doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(doc)[0] # the first data frame

MapLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(doc,"LayerName",dataFrame)
Layer = MapLayers[0]
Layer.definitionQuery = "Field = %s" % Value
Extent = Layer.getExtent(True) # visible extent of layer

dataFrame.extent = Extent
arcpy.RefreshActiveView() # redraw the map
```

The hard part is building the form and accepting/validating the values.. You have to ensure that the definition query is valid; look at [GetCount_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) to ensure that the layer as at least one feature before zooming.

Comment: The "hard" part has only a similar degree of difficulty to do the basics of form input (GetParameterAsText on a Python script tool) and checking for features before zooming (GetCount; as you indicate) because there is no need to validate the Definition Query syntax when all that is being input is an ID as specified in the question.  I think doing something fancier than that should be researched/asked as a new question.

Comment: Yes @PolyGeo if it is run as a script tool nothing fancy need be done. The OP is thinking about a custom form and I think a python add-in. I can really only help with the arcpy in this case as the OP needs to find a form lib (like QT or PyWin) to implement the custom form and seek help on that from Stack Overflow. As a beginner though it might be getting too deep too fast.