# Doing definition query on layer and zooming to it using arcpy.mapping?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, zoom

I am trying to do definition query to a layer and to zoom to the same layer, but I got an error ("SyntaxError: can't assign to operator") ??

`dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0] # the first data frame
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"lyr", dataFrame)[0]:
        Current_Layer=lyr.name
        if lyr.name=="Polygons":
            lyr.definitionQuery = "[Floor] ="+ Floor_num  and "[Physical_number_1] = "= physical_num
            dataFrame.extent=lyr.getSelectedExtent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but I think should work.  It uses Python string formatting syntax.

```
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0] # the first data frame
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"lyr", dataFrame)[0]:
        Current_Layer=lyr.name
        if lyr.name=="Polygons":
            # lyr.definitionQuery = "[Floor] ="+ Floor_num  and "[Physical_number_1] = "= physical_num
            lyr.definitionQuery = "[Floor] = {0} and [Physical_number_1] = {1}".format(Floor_num,physical_num)
            dataFrame.extent=lyr.getSelectedExtent()
```

This is another variation on the theme of [How to zoom to selection in arcpy.mapping and only see selected features?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85231/how-to-zoom-to-selection-in-arcpy-mapping-and-only-see-selected-features)